# Spring @Value default fails to evaluate expression

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations, spring-el

I need to set up thread pool size for scheduled tasks based on either specified property or available resources.
So, I wrote the following code:

```java
@EnableScheduling
@Configuration
public class TaskScheduler{
    
    @Value("${thread.pool.size:#{Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() - 1}}")
    private int threadPoolSize;
    
    @Autowired
    TaskDataRepository repository;
    ...
}
```

However, when I start the code I am getting

> 2024-01-31 11:59:04.217 [METADATA-DEV] [main] [WARN ]
> o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : %PARSER_ERROR[enc]
> 2024-01-31 11:59:04.231 [METADATA-DEV] [main] [INFO ]
> o.s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : %PARSER_ERROR[enc]
> 2024-01-31 11:59:04.259 [METADATA-DEV] [main] [ERROR]
> o.s.boot.SpringApplication : %PARSER_ERROR[enc]
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'taskScheduler': Unsatisfied dependency
> expressed through field 'treadPoolSize': Expression parsing failed    at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:772)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:752)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:145)

Can someone please point out what is wrong with my expression?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static methods cannot be accessed directly, you should use [T operator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/expressions/language-ref/types.html) to get a reference to the `Runtime` type.

```java
@Value("${thread.pool.size:#{T(Runtime).getRuntime().availableProcessors() - 1}}")
private int threadPoolSize;
```

Comment: Thank you. Looks like you are right. I did correct it as you said and I am not getting that error. However, I do have another annotation in the code:
@Scheduled(fixedRateString = "#{${check.rate.minutes} * 60000}")
    public void checkForJobs() {...}
and now I am getting 
2024-01-31 15:22:55.294 [METADATA-DEV] [main] [WARN ] o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : %PARSER_ERROR[enc]

Comment: 2024-01-31 15:22:55.311 [METADATA-DEV] [main] [INFO ] o.s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : %PARSER_ERROR[enc]
2024-01-31 15:22:55.356 [METADATA-DEV] [main] [ERROR] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter : %PARSER_ERROR[enc]
Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
without indication what is wrong. Can you also please advise?

Comment: If you haven't found a solution yet, post a new question since it's not related to this one.

Comment: I posted new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77924658/spring-boot-application-fails-to-start-with-strange-uninformative-messages